# How to extract edge types for all shortest paths in R with igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

igraph has two useful functions, `shortest_paths` and `all_shortest_paths`. The former outputs one of the shortest paths, the other outputs all of them. However, the former also is able to output the edge types of the path while the latter doesn't seem to be able to.

How do I use `all_shortest_paths` to extract the "edge type" for all of the shortest paths? I have provided clarifying code below:

```r
library(igraph)
m <- read.table(row.names=1, header=TRUE, text=
                  " A B C D
                A 0  1  1  0  
                B 0  0 0  1 
                C 0 0  0  1
                D 0  0  0  0")
m <- as.matrix(m)
ig <- graph.adjacency(m, mode="directed")
plot(ig)
E(ig)
for (i in 1:length(E(ig))) {
  
  if (i == 4) {
    
    E(ig)[i]$type <- -1
  } else {

    E(ig)[i]$type <- 1
  }
  
}

###This gets one of the shortest paths
test1 <- shortest_paths(ig, from = V(ig)[1], to = V(ig)[4], mode = "out", output = "epath")

###This outputs the types for the shortest path above
test1$epath[[1]]$type

###This gets all the shortest paths
test2 <- all_shortest_paths(ig, from = V(ig)[1], to = V(ig)[4], mode = "out")

###The code below doesn't work. How do I get the types for ALL the shortest paths?
test2$res[[1]]$type
```

Comment: The underlying C function for `all_shortest_paths` used to return only a sequence of vertices, but not a sequence of edge indices. [It has been recently updated to also return edge indices.](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/1515)  Thus, the necessary update is done for igraph's C core. Feel free to open an issue for R/igraph on GitHub and request that this improvement be propagated to the R interface as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below

```
df <- get.data.frame(ig)
lapply(
  test2$res,
  function(x) {
    nm <- names(x)
    merge(
      df,
      data.frame(from = head(nm, -1), to = tail(nm, -1))
    )$type
  }
)
```

and you will get

```
[[1]]
[1]  1 -1

[[2]]
[1] 1 1
```

---

If you want to see more information, you can use

```
df <- get.data.frame(ig)
lapply(
  test2$res,
  function(x) {
    nm <- names(x)
    merge(
      df,
      data.frame(from = head(nm, -1), to = tail(nm, -1))
    )
  }
)
```

and you will get

```
[[1]]
  from to type
1    A  C    1
2    C  D   -1

[[2]]
  from to type
1    A  B    1
2    B  D    1
```

Comment: Does this work for paths that are longer than 2 edges? I think this step ```from = head(nm, -1), to = tail(nm, -1)``` only applies to my specific example.

Comment: I think it should work for general cases. @Nova

Answer (score 1):

This can be done relatively simply while looping through the `test2$res` and using `igraph`'s accessor function `as_ids()`:

```
suppressMessages(library(igraph))
m <- read.table(row.names=1, header=TRUE, text=
                  " A B C D
                A 0  1  1  0  
                B 0  0 0  1 
                C 0 0  0  1
                D 0  0  0  0")
m <- as.matrix(m)
ig <- graph.adjacency(m, mode="directed")
plot(ig)
E(ig)
for (i in 1:length(E(ig))) {
  if (i == 4) {
    E(ig)[i]$type <- "green"
  } else {
    E(ig)[i]$type <- "red"
  }
}

OriginalGraph <- get.data.frame(x = ig)
EdgeTypesPresent <- vector(mode = "list",
                           length = length(test2))

for (m1 in seq_along(test2$res)) {
  p1 <- as_ids(test2$res[[m1]])
  EdgeTypesPresent[[m1]] <- unique(OriginalGraph$type[OriginalGraph$from %in% p1 &
                                                        OriginalGraph$to %in% p1])
  
}
```

This gives us:

```
> EdgeTypesPresent
[[1]]
[1] "red"   "green"

[[2]]
[1] "red"
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the selections of edges and extract the type:

```
lapply(test2$res, \(x) E(ig)[head(x, -1) %->% tail(x, -1)]$type)
#[[1]]
#[1]  1 -1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 1 1
```

See https://igraph.org/r/doc/igraph-es-indexing.html or `?"igraph-es-indexing"` from inside R for all the details on the options of how this works. E.g.:

```
E(ig)[c("A","B") %->% c("B","D")]
#+ 2/4 edges from 16165ed (vertex names):
#[1] A->B B->D
```